# How to check the validity of token by Oauth provider using Socialite in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was able to use Socialite in my project as per this tutorial : http://www.codeanchor.net/blog/complete-laravel-socialite-tutorial/

Everything worked fine but I have a Security concern in it.

```
if (!$request) {
    return $this->getAuthorizationFirst($provider);
}
```

This checks for token. But is this a correct way to check for token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the tutorial what I noticed is that the `$this->getAuthorizationFirst($provider)` calls the `getAuthorizationFirst` method declared inside the custom `AuthenticateUser` class.

The `getAuthorizationFirst` method simply forces the socialite driver to redirect the user to the provide (Facebook, Github, Twitter, etc.) in order to authenticate the user against the provider. The process then returns the authenticated user back to the calling application.

```
// Authenticate by connecting to the Provider API
private function getAuthorizationFirst($provider) { 
    return $this->socialite->driver($provider)->redirect();
}

// Provider returns authenticated user for post-authentication processing
private function getSocialUser($provider) {
    return $this->socialite->driver($provider)->user();
}
```

This ties in with the processes exposed by Socialite which is to redirect and return to the specified url for post-authentication user processing.

From a security perspective this relies on the application calling the provider's API and getting the authenticated user back.

Socialite is simply exposing a redirect and return method for authentication. You will be unable to do a OAuth authenticate without actually redirecting to the provider API first.

This tutorial looks to be **heavily** based on the tutorial that was put together by Jeffrey Way over at Laracasts.com which can be found here:

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9